# SQL optimization - slow query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Given SQL takes 1.2s:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contracts.id, jt0.id, jt1.id, jt2.id, jt3.id FROM contracts
LEFT JOIN accounts jt0 ON jt0.id = contracts.account_id AND jt0.deleted=0
LEFT JOIN manufacturers jt1 ON jt1.id = contracts.manufacturer_id AND jt1.deleted=0
LEFT JOIN products jt2 ON jt2.id = contracts.product_id AND jt2.deleted=0
LEFT JOIN users jt3 ON jt3.id = contracts.assigned_user_id AND jt3.deleted=0
WHERE contracts.deleted=0
ORDER BY contracts.application_number ASC 
LIMIT 0,21
```

here is what explain extended returns:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows
1   SIMPLE  contracts   ref idx_contracts_deleted   idx_contracts_deleted   2   const   18968   100.00  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  jt0 eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_accnt_id_del,idx_accnt_assigned_del PRIMARY 108 xxx.contracts.account_id    1   100.00  
1   SIMPLE  jt1 eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_manufacturers_id_deleted,idx_manufacturers_deleted  PRIMARY 108 xxx.contracts.manufacturer_id   1   100.00  
1   SIMPLE  jt2 eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_products_id_deleted,idx_products_deleted    PRIMARY 108 xxx.contracts.product_id    1   100.00  
1   SIMPLE  jt3 eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_users_id_del,idx_users_id_deleted,idx_users_deleted PRIMARY 108 xxx.contracts.assigned_user_id  1   100.00
```

I need the distinct, I need all the joins to be left, I need order by and i need limit.
Can i optimize it somehow?

Comment: Is it noticably faster without the DISTINCT or ORDER BY?

Comment: it takes 0.078 without order by and 0.156 without distict

Comment: what's bad about 1.2s anyway? how often do you run it?

Comment: I have to have maximum page refresh time at 2s and with this sql it takes 2.5s to refresh.

Comment: I believe that index on contracts (application_number, deleted, account_id, manufacturer_id, product_id, assigned_user_id) would be helpful. `Deleted` by itself is not enough because it is not very selective (most contracts are probably not deleted anyway).

Answer (score 0):

These are the only suggestions i've got

1. I hope the id's are defined as primary keys and the foreign keys with the relation between the tables.
2. Maybe the application_number can be indexed (then the sort will be faster)
3. Maybe, if you are using MyISAM, the sql could be faster if you lock the tables before selecting (don't forget to unlock afterwards)

Comment: Yes, keys are well defined. Yes, I have index on application_number. I'm using MyIsam - I will check if the lock will help.

Answer (score 0):

First create necessary index on the following columns.

contracts.application_number, manufacturers.deleted, products.deleted, users.deleted

```
SELECT DISTINCT contracts.id, jt0.id, jt1.id, jt2.id, jt3.id 
FROM contracts
LEFT JOIN accounts jt0 
ON contracts.deleted=0 AND jt0.id = contracts.account_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers jt1 
ON jt1.deleted=0 AND jt1.id = contracts.manufacturer_id
LEFT JOIN products jt2 
ON jt2.deleted=0 AND jt2.id = contracts.product_id
LEFT JOIN users jt3 
ON jt3.deleted=0 AND jt3.id = contracts.assigned_user_id
ORDER BY contracts.application_number ASC 
LIMIT 0,21
```

As you have mentioned you are have already index on contracts.deleted

```
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE contracts.deleted = 0 USE INDEX(<deletedIndexName>))
LEFT JOIN 
  accounts jt0 
ON 
  jt0.id = contracts.account_id
LEFT JOIN  
  ...
```

Comment: try creating compound index on following columns in contracts table (account_id, manufacturer_id, product_id, assigned_user_id)

Comment: Yes I tried, it's 1.4s. That compound index you suggested didn't change the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the indexes on the subsidiary tables to include the `deleted` column:

- `accounts(id, deleted)`
- `manufacturers(id, deleted)`
- `products(id, deleted)`
- `users(id, deleted)`

By including all the columns in the index, MySQL has a better opportunity to take advantage of the index.

Another suggestion is to figure out what is causing the duplication in values and to use subqueries to eliminate the duplicates, rather than `distinct`.

For instance, with the above indexes:

```
from contracts c left join
     (select id
      from accounts
      where deleted = 0
      group by id
     ) a
     on c.account_id = a.id
     . . .
```

The subquery should only use the index, which might speed things up.

Comment: I already have the indexes you mentioned. I cannot easily get rid of distinct and replace it with subqueries because of the mechanics behind the application I'm using the SQL in.

Answer (score 0):

Try a little referential integrity?  I bet the query is much faster with inner joins.  It should be, because the query optimizer has more to work with. You're paying the price at `select` time for not taking more care with `create`.

I would also remove deleted rows to their own tables, and strike the `deleted` columns. Your queries will be simpler and likely run faster.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any information about the tables(rows/disk size and etc.) and columns(# of distinct value, point skew values, histgrams). What we got is the query itself, i (or more accurate, the index advice tool i built) give following index recommendations(with explanation this time):

```
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX0823676696 ON contracts(deleted,application_number);
- CONTRACTS(serve as a DRIVE table): INDEX_MATCHING(contracts.deleted=0),SORT_AVOIDANCE(ORDER BY contracts.application_number)

CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX0755052181 ON accounts(ID);
- JT0(serve as a DRIVEN table): INDEX_MATCHING(jt0.id = contracts.account_id AND jt0.deleted=0),INDEX_ONLY(no other columns referenced)

CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX1300536071 ON manufacturers(ID,deleted);
- JT1(serve as a DRIVEN table): INDEX_MATCHING(jt1.id = contracts.manufacturer_id AND jt1.deleted=0),INDEX_ONLY(no other columns referenced)

CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX0776901769 ON users(ID,deleted);
- JT3(serve as a DRIVEN table): INDEX_MATCHING(jt3.id = contracts.assigned_user_id AND jt3.deleted=0),INDEX_ONLY(no other columns referenced)

CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX0863504428 ON products(ID,deleted);
- JT2(serve as a DRIVEN table): INDEX_MATCHING(jt2.id = contracts.product_id AND jt2.deleted=0),INDEX_ONLY(no other columns referenced)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your reminding, explanation added : )